# Getting "wrong number of arguments" from azcopy

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Using version 10.18.0 of azcopy.

Trying to donwload (or copy) blobs from a storage account with the following commando:

```
azcopy.exe cp "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/?[SAS]" ".\MyBlobs" –-recursive=true
```

Getting the following response:

> wrong number of arguments, please refer to the help page on usage of
> this command

But when I change "cp" to "list" and remove the second argument ".\MyBlobs" then it works as expected and lists all the blobs.

Comment: The dash before recursive is en dash `–-`. Replace it with two hyphen `--`. It works. [img1 with –-](https://i.imgur.com/5p4LPJ1.png) and [img2 with --](https://i.imgur.com/xMWujgy.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue is in the dash that you used before recursive flag. I tried the same command with `–-` before recursive and got the same error.

```bash
azcopy.exe cp "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/?[SAS]" ".\MyBlobs" –-recursive=true
```

**Error:**
[image]

- Then replaced the endash with regular hyphen `--` and data is copied without any error.

```bash
azcopy.exe cp "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/?[SAS]" ".\MyBlobs" --recursive=true
```

[image]